# Секции в listView

Tags: java, android, listview

Дело в том, что мне нужно добавить секцию в списке вакансии. То есть "Ранее просмотренные" и в самом начале если есть обновление еще одна секция "Новые". 
Так вот, я храню дату последней просмотренной вакансии в `SharedPreferences` и когда заново запускаю делаю проверку в адаптере на совпадение и меняю `convertView`. Но у меня почему то коряво все работает.

**Секция на место одной вакансии становится при этом эта вакансия не показывается.
И если выйти и сразу запустить приложение, то секция на один пункт ниже опускается, на место другого.**

```
public class SuitableAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VacancyModel> {

private List<VacancyModel> vacancyModelList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private int rowType;

public static String saveLastDate;

public SuitableAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<VacancyModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vacancyModelList = objects;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        switch (rowType){
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suitable_separator_layout, null);
                holder.headerTv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.section_header);
                break;

            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
                holder.tvProfession = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProfession);
                holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
                holder.tvSalary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalary);
                holder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostCr);
                break;
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_SEPARATOR){

        holder.headerTv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.section_header);
        holder.headerTv.setText("Ранее просмотренные");

    }

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_ITEM){

        final VacancyModel model = vacancyModelList.get(position);

        holder.tvProfession.setText(model.getProfession());
        holder.tvHeader.setText(model.getHeader());
        holder.tvSalary.setText(model.getSalary());
        holder.tvDate.setText(model.getDate());

        Date date;
        try {
            if (saveLastDate == null){
                saveLastDate = model.getDate();
            } else {
                date = stringToDate(saveLastDate);
                if (date.before(stringToDate(model.getDate()))){
                    saveLastDate = model.getDate();
                }
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (GlobalData.LoadDate(getContext()) == null){
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    } else {
        VacancyModel model = getItem(position);

        if (model != null){
            String newString = model.getDate();
            String lastString = GlobalData.LoadDate(getContext());

            Date newDate = null;
            Date lastDate = null;

            try {
                newDate = stringToDate(newString);
                lastDate = stringToDate(lastString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            assert newDate != null;
            return newDate.equals(lastDate) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
        }
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return vacancyModelList.size() + rowType;
}

private Date stringToDate(String string) throws ParseException {
    return new SimpleDateFormat(("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), Locale.getDefault()).parse(string);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvProfession;
    private TextView tvHeader;
    private TextView tvSalary;
    private TextView tvDate;

    private TextView headerTv;
}
```

}

Вопрос: Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Покажите полный стек-трейс.

Comment: Почему не переопределить реализуемые адаптером методы `getItemViewType()` и `getViewTypeCount()`, они именно для такого, как в вашем вопросе, предназначены и реализуют механизм более правильно

Comment: @pavloff, так и сделал. NullPointer исчез, но смена секции то вниз то вверх не исправился. Я понял, что секция на место одной вакансии становится при этом эта вакансия не показывается.

Comment: Вам нужно добавить количество разделителей, а не rowType. И исправить определение типа элемента. Вы не учитываете что в position включены и разделители

Comment: Не совсем понял, какие разделители? Тип элемента?

Comment: Вы хотите отобразить несколько элементов 2х разных типов в одном list view. Часть этих элементов - разделители. Те, что с типом TYPE_SEPARATOR. Вот теперь вопрос: разделители должны быть между всеми элементами, или нет? Логика определения типа очень непрозрачная.

Comment: Ааа нет они должны быть только там где уже просмотрели и в самом начале где новые если после просмотренных появились новые вакансии. В двух местах только.

Comment: Ок, видимо для того чтобы отображать разделитель как отдельный элемент нужна довольно сложная логика. Тогда есть 2 варианта:
1). Отображать разделитель как часть обычного элемента. Т.е. в suitable_separator_layout добавить вью из row_layout и в getView, когда `rowType == TYPE_SEPARATOR`, нужно заполнять tvProfession, tvSalary и т.д.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49047/discussion-between-lllyct-and-titan).

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException выскакивает из-за того что ListView пытается повторно использовать уже созданный View. При этом вызывается getView() с convertView != null. Новый View не создается, а лайаут уже созданного View не соответствует типу элемента. Нужно переопределить `getItemViewType()` и `getViewTypeCount()`, тогда ListView будет знать какой тип использовать для данного конкретного элемента.

В вашем случае getViewTypeCount должен возвращать 2, а getItemViewType - 0 или 1, в зависимости от элемента, как вы это определяете в getType(). Очень важно чтобы возвращались именно значения от 0 до count-1, по тому что ListView не поддерживает не последовательные индексы типов. Вот если бы вы использовали RecyclerView, то можно было бы использовать layout в качестве идентификатора типа.

Еще у вас при определении типа не учитывается количество разделителей. Т.е. если у вас есть элементы 0, 1, 2, 3, и разделитель между 1 и 2, то для элемента "3" position должен быть 4, а не 3. И общее число элементов должно быть items.size() + separators.size()

Comment: А как задать общее число элементов?

Comment: Надо переопределить метод `getCount()` адаптера.

Comment: Вот что я написал, вроде это должно было решить проблему, но вот rowType всегда нолем остается не меняется, думаю он не обновляется, то есть обновляется внутри getView. А можно ли его обновить перед тем как getView сработает?

`@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return vacancyModelList.size() + rowType;
    }`

Comment: Надо обновить код в шапке, не понятно что за rowType и где вы его обновляете.

Comment: обновил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы не переопределили getItemViewType. По умолчанию этот метод всегда возвращает 0, а вам надо его переопределить и реализовать там вашу логику из getType, с учетом нюанса про допустимые значения. Т.е. если у вас TYPE_SEPARATOR = 0, а TYPE_ITEM = 1 (или наоборот), то можно прото скопировать логику из getType в getItemViewType

Comment: Извините, забыл это исправление залить, сделал как написали